# How does one resolve: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1 error? for video compress

Tags: flutter, gradle, build

Trying to run my app on the emulator but keep getting this error:

> e: C:\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\video_compress-2.0.0\android\src\main\kotlin\com\example\video_compress\VideoCompressPlugin.kt: (25, 7): Redeclaration: VideoCompressPlugin
> e: C:\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\video_compress-2.1.0\android\src\main\kotlin\com\example\video_compress\VideoCompressPlugin.kt: (28, 7): Redeclaration: VideoCompressPlugin
> e: C:\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\video_compress-2.1.0\android\src\main\kotlin\com\example\video_compress\VideoCompressPlugin.kt: (184, 28): Cannot access '': it is private in 'VideoCompressPlugin'
> e: C:\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\video_compress-2.1.0\android\src\main\kotlin\com\example\video_compress\VideoCompressPlugin.kt: (184, 48): No value passed for parameter 'activity'
> e: C:\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\video_compress-2.1.0\android\src\main\kotlin\com\example\video_compress\VideoCompressPlugin.kt: (184, 48): No value passed for parameter 'context'
> e: C:\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\video_compress-2.1.0\android\src\main\kotlin\com\example\video_compress\VideoCompressPlugin.kt: (184, 48): No value passed for parameter 'channel'
> e: C:\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\video_compress-2.1.0\android\src\main\kotlin\com\example\video_compress\VideoCompressPlugin.kt: (185, 22): Unresolved reference: init

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':video_compress:compileDebugKotlin'.

> Compilation error. See log for more details

**What I have tried so far:**

- running Flutter doctor  no issues.
- Changing down and up versions of the video compress dependency no change (video_compress: ^2.1.0)
- Update flutter to latest version (currently 51.0.2)
- Adding flutter_svg: ^0.18.0 to the pubspec
- Flutter clean
- Invalidate caches in Android Studio

**A possible offender?**

```
_submit() async {
if (videoList.isEmpty || outputPath.isEmpty) return;

if (!isLoading) {
  setState(() {
    isLoading = true;
  });
}
print('LOG: outputPath: $outputPath');
var outPutFileExists = await File(outputPath).exists();
print('LOG: output file exists $outPutFileExists');

videoUrl = await StorageService.uploadVideo(File(outputPath));
imageUrl = await StorageService.uploadVideoThumbnail(File(outputPath));

Post post = Post(
    imageUrl: imageUrl,
    videoUrl: videoUrl,
    likeCount: 0,
    authorId: Provider.of<UserData>(context).currentUserId,
    timestamp: Timestamp.fromDate(DateTime.now()),
    viewCount: 0,
    mode: 'Beginner',
    cardId: widget.card.card[0],
    category: widget.card.category,
    flagged: false,
    flags: []);
```

**Another possibility:**

```
 static Future<MediaInfo> compressVideo(File file) async {
    final info = await VideoCompress.compressVideo(
      file.path,
      quality: VideoQuality.HighestQuality,
      deleteOrigin: false,
    );

    return info;
  }
```

Third try:

```
    static Future<String> uploadVideo(File videoFile) async {
    String videoId = Uuid().v4();
    MediaInfo videoInfo = await compressVideo(videoFile);
    StorageUploadTask uploadTask =
        storageRef.child('videos/video_$videoId.mp4').putFile(videoInfo.file);

    StorageTaskSnapshot storageSnap = await uploadTask.onComplete;
    String downloadUrl = await storageSnap.ref.getDownloadURL();
    return downloadUrl;
  }

  static Future<String> uploadVideoThumbnail(File videoFile) async {
    String photoId = Uuid().v4();
    final thumbnailFile = await VideoCompress.getFileThumbnail(videoFile.path,
        quality: 100, // default(100)
        position: -1 // default(-1)
        );
    StorageUploadTask uploadTask = storageRef
        .child('images/thumbnails/image_$photoId.jpg')
        .putFile(thumbnailFile);
    StorageTaskSnapshot storageSnap = await uploadTask.onComplete;
    String downloadUrl = await storageSnap.ref.getDownloadURL();
    return downloadUrl;
  }
```

Would be very grateful for any guidance.

Tom

Comment: hey by going through your error message it got there is something wrong with your method channel, whatever information you provided is not enough please provide your mainActivity code where channel is defined as well as relative flutter code

Comment: Hey Atul, there isn't much information in the MainActivity file. Did you need to see the entire page code to see where the error is?

Comment: are you using method channel for accessing some platform specific functionality??. if yes then share all code related to main activity and flutter code from where you are accessing your method channel

Comment: Hey Atul, please see above. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the answer was my main.dart file was outside the lib folder for various reasons. I moved it back into lib.

In addition to this I deleted the gradle file from the Android Studio project tab and then rebuilt. I also file > Invalidated caches. Seemed to do the trick for now.

Answer (score 4):

I think when you were updating to *video_compress* **v2.1.0**, you still had version **v2.0.0** cached. Thus, the *"Redeclaration"* error in the log. You might want to run this in your terminal:

`flutter clean && flutter packages get`

Answer (score 0):

try to add this package `flutter_svg: ^0.18.0` in pubsec.yaml and then try again.

and also try these given steps
https://nabil6391.medium.com/solutions-to-flutter-error-gradle-task-assembledebug-failed-with-exit-code-1-1d2c36b2001a

Comment: Hey Mohammad, thanks no change when adding flutter_svg: ^0.18.0 to the pubspec :(

Comment: @nerdMonkey then its better option to try another package for video compression

Answer (score 0):

Open Android module of flutter project in Android studio.

From Menu, `Build -> Clean`

Now run. It will work